# Xcode4 source control problem

Tags: svn, core-data, repository, xcode4

I have a project under SVN, which was last used with previous version of Xcode (Xcode 3.x). Now when i try to Open the same project with Xcode 4, it doesn't show the .xcdatamodeld file under source-control.

If i modify the .xcdatamodeld file (e.g. add a new model version), i don't get any source-control symbols (e.g. "A", "U"). After applying the changes, when i go to File > Source Control > Commit, i see the .xcdatamodeld file on the left pane, but the checkbox is disabled, and the file has a "?" and "A" next to it.

How can i fix this?

Edit:
Can i somehow delete the .xcdatamodeld file from the subversion directory (on server), and re-add it, so that it's recognized as a new file? Will that affect how the .xcdatamodeld file handles versioning?